# Converting String Versions of "Infinity" to Numeric in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I have some JSON response that encodes Inf/-Inf/NaN as strings, so the JSON array it returns will look like `[1.0, "Infinity", 2.0]`. I parse this using a JSON library and end up with a list that looks like `list(1.0, "Infinity", 2.0)` and I want to convert it to be `list(1.0, Inf, 2.0)`, for performance reasons I need this to use Rcpp. Here is the code I tried doing but I can't seem to get Rcpp to not yell at me about

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('
NumericVector convertThings(List data) {
  const size_t num_rows = data.size();
  NumericVector rv(num_rows);
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i) {
    if (as<String>(data[i]) == "Infinity") {
      rv[i] = R_PosInf;
    } else {
      rv[i] = as<double>(data[i]);
    }
  }
  return rv;
}
')

convertThings(list('Infinity', 1.0))
# expected output c(Inf, 1.0)
```

The error I am seeing is `Error: not compatible with requested type`. Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a basic C++ problem: how to convert *text* to *numbers* reliably.

One possibly answer is provided by the [Boost.Lexical_Cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) library and illustrated in [this Rcpp Gallery post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/a-second-boost-example/).  Just using the first example:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/boostLexicalCastExample.cpp")  # from post
R> lexcicalCast(c("Inf", "inf", "Infinity", "NA", 42))
[1] Inf Inf Inf  NA  42
R>
```

As you can see, it matches at least three different ways of spelling infinity in text.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks so much Dirk!